# Linq contains for compairing two huge list takes long time

Tags: c#, .net, performance, list, linq

When i want to compare a huge list (about 700,000 elements) with a specific property and list of string, takes long time.

I tried AsParallel but it doesn't help me any more. i need list for removedSuccessFromList because i want to use this list for start a Parallel.Foreach

```
List<string> successStrings = service.GetProperty().Select(q => 
q.IdString).ToList();

List<Property> removedSuccessFromList = properties.AsParallel().Where(q => 
!successStrings.Contains(q.IdString)).ToList();
```

Comment: "Takes a long time"... How was that benchmark achieved? And how do you perform comparisons of one "long time" to another "long time"?

Comment: how big is `successStrings`? how big is `properties`? the sizes can matter

Comment: @Evk I'm *assuming* that `properties` is the 700k, but: yes, it would be good to know the sizes of the two inputs

Answer (score 3):

Use mre effective data structure if you have lot of strings in `successStrings`, like hash set:

```
var successStrings = new HashSet<string>(service.GetProperty().Select(q => q.IdString));

List<Property> removedSuccessFromList = properties.Where(q => !successStrings.Contains(q.IdString)).ToList();
```

`List.Contains` method has complexity O(N), so it scan all elements to find match. `HashSet.Contains` has complexity O(1) - it can check if element exists very vast.

Comment: Note that O(1) can be slower than O(N), especially for small N. Whether this is an *actual improvement* depends hugely on the size of `successStrings`

Answer (score 0):

If your `IdString` is unique maybe you could remove each founded item from successStrings in the `Where` logic so the list get smaller eventually

Comment: this would not automatically be an improvement; and since OP is using parallel, it would introduce a need to synchronize, which could add significant impact

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, I would recommend to don't use parallel, to run O(N) algorithm on just 16 core. Running better algorithm on one core should be more efficient

Comment: this method will takes so long too but i can see the progress.